# Salesforce - pass parameter to controller from inputfield

Tags: salesforce

How can you pass a parameter from visualforce page with an inputfield to the controller?

With inputText works, but I need inputField:

```
<apex:inputText id="firstname" value="{!firstname}" html-placeholder="{!Offer__c.Name__c}" disabled="true"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!submit}" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a contact record exposed in Controller as below:

public Contact currentContact {get;set;}

Then you can reference this in a Visualforce page as below:

You can get more information here [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm)